# How to add xfce4-panel plugin to the specific panel via terminal?

Tags: bash, plugins, terminal, panel, xfce

I have an installed plugin, that I want to add to the panel. I can always do that via xfce4-panel GUI. But my question is how can I do that via terminal so no GUI is being called.

`xfce4-panel --add=PLUGIN-NAME` will call GUI asking for a panel number.

`xfce4-panel --add-items=PANEL-NUMBER` will call GUI asking for a plugin to be added.

How can I combine these commands so no GUI will be called, i.e. is there a way to add a plugin to the specific panel, assuming that I know panel’s number?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this is currently possible. Reading the source code, I found that those commands just dispatch calls to dbus methods [1](https://git.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/tree/panel/panel-dbus-service.c?id=b823f32749ff7ec8d2abc4d10fd7457b628cdcdd#n256) [2](https://git.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/tree/panel/panel-dbus-service.c?id=b823f32749ff7ec8d2abc4d10fd7457b628cdcdd#n216), and their implementation do not support what you need. You can try to [file a bug](http://bugzilla.xfce.org/) requesting this improvement.

Comment: @AndreLDM Thank you for your interest. It’s possible, I figured out a solution using `xfconf-query`, but I never had time to upload the answer. But I’ll be doing that, once I have some free time.

Comment: @MOPO3OB we are still waiting...

Comment: Add answer myself, better late than never.

Answer (score 4):

So far, the panel and plugins settings in XFCE is saving in own database, wich can be controlled either editing xml files at `$HOME/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml` folder, either using command-line util 'xfconf-query', either via GUI tool for that called `xfce4-settings-editor`.

The panels data in that database are stored in channel 'xfce4-panel' under property '/panels'. Each panel contains their plugins list in their order under "/panels/panel-0/plugin-ids" property, where "panel-0" is panel name.

These ids point to all available plugins that are listed in the same channel "xfce4-panel" under property "/plugins".

So for adding new plugin to panel programmatically you need:

1. add plugin by name to the "/plugins" property
2. add that plugin id to the "/plugin-ids" property of selected panel

Some code:

```sh
# xfconf-query not yet support adding individual entries to array 
# so need override all plugins in the panel
# before using this command adapt it to your current list 
# of plugins + simply add your new
# copying and executing this command without adopting may broke your panel 
# do not execute as is
xfconf-query -n -c xfce4-panel -p "/panels/panel-0/plugin-ids" -a \
            -t int -s 1  -t int -s 2  -t int -s 3  -t int -s 4  -t int -s 5  \
            -t int -s 6  -t int -s 7  -t int -s 8  -t int -s 9  -t int -s 10 \
            -t int -s 11 -t int -s 12 -t int -s 13
# so last 13 is our new plugin id, lets add it

# adding new plugin with id 13, lets this be 'xkb' plugin (language layout switcher)
xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -pn "/plugins/plugin-13" -t string -s 'xkb'

# restart panels for taking effect
xfce4-panel --restart
```